# Declaring at an airport with Diabetes

Tags: international-travel, health

I do not have diabetes, but my partner does.

We are looking to go on holiday in the next few months but one thing I have been unsure of is whether we should be declaring her medicine or to go through nothing to declare as normal?

Can this depend on the country or do all follow the same rules for diabetic medication?

Comment: It does depend on the country, so do check with the site of your airline or airport, the information should be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you are asking because the medication includes injections and not only oral medicine.

This depends slightly on the country but in most cases I have been involved with you bring the medication, syringes etc and a doctors prescription to the check in, and they will advice you from there.

Normally on the aircraft the crew will take care of your medication and the syringes as they will not let you keep it for yourself and when you need to medicate ( or your partner ) you will tell them and they will give you access to the medicine in a controlled manner.

I am assuming the flight in question is long enough that you need to medicate in the air.

Be aware that some airlines do not allow you to fly with them due to this condition, I have had a friend refused to fly with China Eastern a few years back as they do not allow needles on their aircraft even with a doctors note, note however that this was back in 2017 and might have changed.

As a recommendation it is always a good idea to call the airline and check what you need to prepare for this situation so that you dont get surprises on the day of travel.

Comment: Correct assumption, thank you for this answer. I shall keep it in mind when we decide where to go.

Comment: In most cases I have heard about the passenger keeps their medication themselves and syringes and needles are not a problem.

Comment: @Willeke yeah it depends on country and airline but also most meds that used syringes etc needs to be kept in cool temperatures which means the airplane cool storage, my dad is a diabetic and we have travelled frequently and most common during our 30 years of travelling is that the crew keeps the needles and medicine at least for the last 10 years or so, before that things were different heck I remember when I was in the Air Force back in the days we even brought knives on commercial flights

Answer (score 1):

While I‘m not diabetic, there are a lot of self-help pages by interest groups - the [ADA has US-centric air travel information](https://www.diabetes.org/resources/know-your-rights/discrimination/public-accommodations/air-travel-and-diabetes) for example.

In general, you should be allowed to take all necessary supplies (including syringes and larger amount of liquids) on the flight, though you need to submit them for inspection at security.

However, your question seems to be about at the customs channel when you arrive. If and what you have to declare depends on the destination country, because each had their own rules. You could check your government‘s travel advisories, a travel guide or even with the embassy of your destination country.

Or you just declare the supplies at customs just in case.